# Ros-Control four_wheel_steering_controller no-commands output

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I try to use the four_wheel_steering_controller from Ros-Control. I set it up as in the example file on github. cmd_vel gets subsribed to by the controller and teleop_twist_keyboard generates data.
However the "steering_joints_[i].position_command" outputs Zero. The same with the velocity commands.

Anybody got a hint how to hunt down the problem? Now and Then I get a control period overtime warning, but I dont think this schould shutoff the controller.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341136/ros-control-four_wheel_steering_controller-no-commands-output/) by [Dragonslayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38812/dragonslayer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 574 on 2020-01-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-07**:
Is the controller started? That would be the first thing I'd check.

**Comment by [Dragonslayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38812/dragonslayer/) on 2020-01-07**:
Thanks for the reply. The controller seems running, rosservice call controller_manager/list_controllers shows it running, the Logfiles shows its started without any issue. As [link text](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/blob/melodic-devel/four_wheel_steering_controller/test/src/four_wheel_steering.h) shows they are using a ServiceServer, I dont know about that, maybe that isnt up and running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Question can be closed, was just a typo in the topic remap :/

EDIT: The remap was by "rosrun teleop_twist_keyboard teleop_twist_keyboard.py cmd_vel:=[mybot]/four_wheel_steering_controller/cmd_vel"
When I first ran it it was correct, thus pub and sub was OK. But I then by mistake must have changed the command to "four_wheel_steering_controller/cmd_ve[missing the "l"]" As I start and stopped the node I just use "Arrow up" to get the same/last command again in the console, thus this error occured on and on. My confusion was because I thought I use the correct command as it once was, but changed it inadvertendly, maybe by trying to write something in another window that wasnt really active yet.

---

Originally posted by [Dragonslayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38812/dragonslayer/) with karma: 574 on 2020-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-09**:
No need to close it.

Please expand on your answer and accept it as the answer.

What exactly was the problem (ie: what was the `remap`, and what should it have been)?